# Bind colors to categories in d3 charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data that looks something like this:

```
groupA = [{'race': 'Black',  'count': 7}, 
{'race': 'White',  'count': 8}, 
{'race': 'unknown', 'count': 3}]


groupB = [{'race': 'White',  'count': 5}, 
{'race': 'Asian',  'count': 8}, 
{'race': 'Black',  'count': 6}, 
{'race': 'unknown', 'count': 4}]

groupC = [{'race': 'Black',  'count': 5}, 
{'race': 'White',  'count': 8},
{'race': 'unknown', 'count': 10},
{'race':'Asian', 'count':5} 
{'race': 'Hispanic', 'count': 4}]

//...and so on
```

I am using it in d3 to build pie charts.  I have an html select option to choose which group data to display on the pie chart.
Everything works fine except that I want the same color to represent the same category each time a chart is rendered.  There are 5 race categories but not every category is represented in each group.

I defined the colors like this:

```
var race_color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#1B9E77", "#D95F02", "#7570B3", "#E7298A", "#66A61E"]);
```

I am using this to fill the slices:

```
arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i){
        return race_color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", function (d) {
        return arc(d);
    })
```

But what I need to do is to bind the same race category to the same color slice.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using index position `i`, as in `race_color(i)` doesn't work because at times, when `i` is 0 race is `"Black"` (groups A, C), and in another case it's `"White"` (group B).

Instead, key the colors by the actual race value `race_color(d.race)`, which remains consistent across groups.

Answer (score 1):

For example, please prepare color table like this.

```
var color_table = {
    'Black'   : '#1B9E77',
    'White'   : '#D95F02',
    'Asian'   : '#7570B3',
    'Hispanic': '#E7298A',
    'unknown' : '#66A61E'
};
```

And modify your code like this.

```
arcs.append("svg:path")
.attr("fill", function(d, i){
    return color_table[d.race]; // modified
})
.attr("d", function (d) {
    return arc(d);
})
```